# Getting the value of an integer array from LIST<>

Tags: c#, list, random

Can anyone tell me why the message box is not displaying the value of the random number? I'm trying to get 10 random numbers and display them one at a time in a message box. The numbers can repeat, and should be between 1 and 4.

```
public void GetRandomPattern()
        {
            List<int> pattern = new List<int>();

            rounds = 10;
            Random number = new Random();

            for (int counter = 0; counter < rounds; counter++)
            {
                pattern.Add(number.Next(1, 4));
                MessageBox.Show(pattern.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is `pattern`?

Comment: I added the pattern code, sorry. It's an integer List.

Comment: Try : MessageBox.Show(string.join(",",pattern.Select(x => x.ToString())));

Comment: Because you are displaying the list, not the number?

Answer (score 2):

`pattern` is a `List<int>`.  When you do `.ToString()` on that it's on the whole object (i.e. all of the items, not just one).  `List` doesn't provide a way to display the items, so it just returns the type.

To display one number at a time you'll want to do this instead:

```
pattern[counter].ToString()
```

That will select the specific item in your List since `counter` matches the current index of your List.

Comment: Thank you!  @MikeH That is what I was wanting to do. Works perfectly. I appreciate all the answers.

Answer (score 2):

If not overridden, `ToString()` will show you the name of object's type. In your case it will show name of `List<int>` type:

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]

If you want to display content of list, you should create string manually. E.g.

```
 var formattedPattern = String.Join(", ", pattern); // "2, 1, 3, 2"
 MessageBox.Show(formattedPattern );
```

If you want to show individual items of list on each iteration, you can refer them by index as @MikeH suggests, or just use a temporary variable for that

```
 var nextNumber = number.Next(1, 4);
 pattern.Add(nextNumber);
 MessageBox.Show(nextNumber.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to display a list object in message box. instead try below code

```
 for (int counter = 0; counter < rounds; counter++)
            {
                var randNo = number.Next(1, 4);
                pattern.Add(randNo );
                MessageBox.Show(randNo);
            }
```